# Can you use .load() to load html into div's with dynamic id's?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to load html into div's that have dynamically created id's by passing the id to the function as a data attribute. Doesn't seem to work though.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('input:radio').on('ifChecked', function(event){
            var clauseDivID = $(this).data("clause-div-id");
        $("#" + clauseDivID).load("inc-files/test.htm #test", function() {
                alert("The load was performed.");
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: "Doesn't seem to work" is not a very good diagnostic statement. Have you tried stepping through this in the debugger to see what variables are being set? Is that URL even valid? Also worth noting, using `console.log` is a lot less intrusive than `alert`.

Comment: Realistically, it is possible. If 'clauseDivID' is a div, it should be added to the page first before loading html into it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like this?   Please look at the valid event names for jQuery. 'ifChecked' is not one.  http://api.jquery.com/category/events/

```
        $('input[type="radio"]').on('change', function (e) {
            if($(this).prop('checked'))
            {
               var clauseDivID = $(this).data("clause-div-id");
               $("#" + clauseDivID).load("inc-files/test.htm #test", function() {
                   alert("The load was performed.");
               });
            }


        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer, just a couple of things to try. Please let us know the results if this doesn't lead you to the solution:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(document).on('ifChecked', function(event){
            alert('received the click');
        });
    });
</script>


<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(document).on('ifChecked', function(event){
            var clauseDivID = $(this).data("clause-div-id");
            alert('clauseDivID: ' + clauseDivID );
        });
    });
</script>
```